# How to abstract null/undefined checking with Flow?

Tags: node.js, casting, type-conversion, flowtype

`sessionStorage.getItem()` is treated as Maybe/Optional type by Flow. So the following is necessary to make the result usable as a string type that is not of Optional type or of Maybe type:

```
const accessToken1 = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')
if (!accessToken1) throw new Error('Unwrapping not possible because the variable is null or undefined!')
'Hello ' + accessToken1 // no complaints by Flow
```

Now I want to abstract the null/undefined checking, but Flow does not stop complaining about the possible null and undefined types:

```
function unwrap<T>(value: T): T {
  if (!value) throw new Error('Unwrapping not possible because the variable is null or undefined!')
  return value // at this point Flow should understand it cannot be of type Optional or Maybe
}

'Hello ' + unwrap('World!')     // works
'Hello ' + unwrap(null)         // complains as expected with "null This type cannot be added to string"
'Hello ' + unwrap(undefined)    // complains as expected with "null This type cannot be added to string"
const nullString = 'null'
'Hello ' + unwrap(nullString)   // works
const accessToken2 = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')
'Hello ' + unwrap(accessToken2) // null/undefined This type cannot be added to string
const accessToken3 = (sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'): string) // null/undefined This type cannot be added to string
'Hello ' + unwrap(accessToken3) // no complaints by Flow
```

Comment: I don't like this flow behavior either.  Do you actually need `unwrap` to throw an error in the case of a `null` value?

Comment: You don't have to throw. You could do an unsafe cast within `unwrap`, i.e. `function unwrap<T>(value: ?T): T { return ((value:any):T); }`, although I would call it `unsafe_cast`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return type is widening the refinement back to its original type. Try

```
function unwrap<T>(value: ?T): T { // Note the `?T`
    if (!value) throw new Error('Unwrapping not possible because the variable is null or undefined!')
    return value // at this point Flow should understand it cannot be of type Optional or Maybe
}
```

Some of your comments seem misguided. Here are the necessary corrections that I see:

```
'Hello ' + unwrap(null) // Not an error (I've opted for runtime errors with my `throw`)
'Hello ' + unwrap(undefined) // Not an error (I've opted for runtime errors with my `throw`)
```